# Selecting a child div with a class inside an event handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child, children

I am not sure on how to do this

I have

```
<div class="a parent">
 <div class="child">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="b parent">
 <div class="child">
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to something like this (in pseudocode)

```
$(".parent").mousemove(function(){

 select the `.child` which is the child of this div


})
```

so when `.a` is hovered on it will select a's `.child` only, and when `.b` is hovered on it will select b's `.child` only

This should involve `this` or `$this` or `$(this)` or something similar.. but its confusing and I don't know where to read about it

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? The jQuery function is described [in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1), as well as [all the traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/). Spending some time reading through the API documentation is worthwhile. Maybe the [Getting started](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) tutorial is helpful for you as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will select all children with the `.child` class.

```
$(".parent").mousemove(function() {
    var children = $(this).children('.child');
});
```

With this you can select the first child with the `.eq()` method.

```
if (children.length > 0) {
    var firstChild = children.eq(0);
}
```

You can also select from descendants (from children's children...) using the function `.find()`, not part of the question but related and useful to know.

```
var descendants = $(this).find('.child');
```

Comment: You can just do `$(this).children('.child').first()` for selecting the first `.child` child/descendant.